# Primefaces push atmosphere spring security configuration

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, push, atmosphere

I am working on JSF Web Application with using

*Primefaces 6.0,*

*Spring Framework 4,*

*Glassfish 4.1.1*

when i add atmosphere dependency, spring beans are not working but i can chat other users. 
when i remove atmosphere dependency, everything is fine again.

i think, i can not configure spring and primefaces push .

**How can I configure  primefaces push - atmosphere with spring?**

My project files..

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6</version>

    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

ChatResource.java

```
@PushEndpoint("/chat/{user}")
public class NotifyResource {


    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public Message onMessage(Message c) {
        return c;
    }
}
```

chat.xhtml

```
 <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/chat/#{sessionBean.user.username}">
            </p:socket>
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleMessage(message) {

                     .........

            }
   </script>
```

ChatBean.java

```
private final EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
.
.
.
CHANNEL = "/chat/" + message.getReceiverName().get(i); //for example : "/chat/ali"
eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, message);
```

SpringSecurity.xml //configuration file

```
.
.
.
.
 <sec:http pattern="/primepush/chat/**" security="none" />
   <sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"  >
        <sec:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"   />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/login.xhtml" access="permitAll"  />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"  />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/xxxxx.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()"  />


        <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/Accessdenied" />
        <sec:form-login  login-page="/Login"   /> 
        <sec:logout  logout-success-url="/pages/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"  invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true"/>
        <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>

        <sec:custom-filter ref="sessionManagementFilter" before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" />  
    </sec:http>
```